# How can I round up MyBB View count format

Tags: mybb

Am Using MyBB for my forum,
My post view always display as e.g 31344, 211313

How can I round it up to something like 31k, 21k
And when it reach million or billions it should be 31M, 21B

You Get The Idea?, please how can I fixed that

Remember am using MyBB

Answer (score 0):

For that, you need to edit the function `my_number_format` in stats.php file in global directory.

It responsibility is to parse the number in a given format.